# Wamp server, localhost and phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I installed Wamp server to windows XP 32-bit.

When start the Wamp server and call the localhost from the browser,
the browser gives me empty an page. The same thing happens when calling phpMyAdmin page.

So I searched for solutions to this problem. I've tried to fix it but until now the problem is not solved.

### About the problem that fixed it

1- UnInstall the skype . or change the port that skype used it from 80 .to another port number
2- if you install oracle to your pc . turn off the service for it 
3- also if you install sqlserver . turn off the service for it

### 4-if the last problems and the problem of wamp server is stilling. change the port that used it from 80 to 8080 .

I do all of theses steps but the wamp server untill now not worked

Answer (score 0):

you should look for the reason WAMP is not working:

- you do havs a 32bit OS, do you have a 32Bit WAMP? A 64Bit Version will not work
- if you don't see anything at all of Apache running, is Apache running (Tasklist) ?
- What about the Logfiles? I never used an Apache on Windows, Google told me your logfiles should be located at: c:/wamp/logs . Anything in there that might help?

Answer (score 0):

check the steps before you handing the WAMP Server:

- use 32 bit WAMP server.
- change the port no 80 to 81.
- Stop the IIS services.
- Start the Apache server.
- restart the WAMP server.

use the port no in your URL.Like.

http: // localhost:81 /

now you can view the screen of WAMP server.

Comment: Dear sir,I Test all steps as you said put not running

Comment: uninstall the wamp server, then goto regitry delete the files related to wamp server apache server then restart your pc. again install the wamp server.